# Race conditions MariaDB

Tags: php, database, mariadb, race-condition

Im trying to find a solution to a MariaDB race condition.
There are some cases where multiple process get executed almost at the same time (with the same timestamp that comes from some units in the field) and they need to read the same row each one (but only the first one needs to perform the action).

I was thinking to lock the row (only the row, locking the entire table is not an option), so the first process will read it and check the timestamp of the latest update, perform the task needed and once is unlocked the other processes will be able to read it, and if it has the same timestamp just ignore it.

It will affect performance, but only for those few cases where this happens.

I've been trying to do this in MariaDB, but I can't find the how... starting a transaction and executing FOR UPDATE seems to lock the entire table, because I'm not able to fetch another rows meanwhile.

And reading MariaDB documentation I see this

> When LOCK IN SHARE MODE is specified in a SELECT statement, MariaDB will wait until all transactions that have modified the rows are committed. Then, a write lock is acquired. All transactions can read the rows, but if they want to modify them, they have to wait until your transaction is committed.

So basically, what I want to do can't be done in MariaDB?

Any ideas?

Thank you,

Comment: If you are checking rows based on timestamps couldn't you use a WHERE condition in your action/update so that it only happens if the timestamp is different?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the query that you have tentatively built.

Comment: I think the `FOR UPDATE` (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/for-update/) clause might better serve your need.